# Trying to get data from graphql in angular, watchQuery is giving error

Tags: angular, graphql

my code is as follow

```
hotels: Observable<Hotel[]>;
  a = {
    Query: gql`
      query getHotels {
        getHotels {
          id
          hotel_name
          street
          city
          postalcode
          price
          email
        }
      }
    `,
  };

  constructor(private apollo: Apollo) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.hotels = this.apollo
      .watchQuery<Query>(this.a)
```

the error i am getting is

**Type '{ Query: DocumentNode; }' has no properties in common with type 'WatchQueryOptions'.ts(2559)**

what could be reason and possible solution ?
any leades would be appreciated.

my types.ts is

```
import { type } from "os";

export type Hotel = {
  id: string;
  hotel_name: string;
  street: string;
  city: string;
  postalcode: string;
  price: string;
  email: string;
};

export type Query = {
  allHotels: Hotel[];
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error states that the structure of your variable `a` is { Query: DocumentNode; } but it has to be like this: `{ query: DocumentNode; }`. No Uppercase `Query` but lowercase. It is just a type error, the object you provide to `.watchQuery` is defined as follows:

```
export interface QueryBaseOptions<TVariables = OperationVariables> {
  /**
   * A GraphQL document that consists of a single query to be sent down to the
   * server.
   */
  // TODO REFACTOR: rename this to document. Didn't do it yet because it's in a
  // lot of tests.
  query: DocumentNode;

  /**
   * A map going from variable name to variable value, where the variables are used
   * within the GraphQL query.
   */
  variables?: TVariables;

  /**
   * Specifies the {@link ErrorPolicy} to be used for this query
   */
  errorPolicy?: ErrorPolicy;

  /**
   * Context to be passed to link execution chain
   */
  context?: any;
}


export interface WatchQueryOptions<TVariables = OperationVariables>
  extends QueryBaseOptions<TVariables>,
    ModifiableWatchQueryOptions<TVariables> {
  /**
   * Specifies the {@link FetchPolicy} to be used for this query.
   */
  fetchPolicy?: WatchQueryFetchPolicy;
  /**
   * Specifies the {@link FetchPolicy} to be used after this query has completed.
   */
  nextFetchPolicy?: WatchQueryFetchPolicy;
}
```